# Will my operator-dependent phone work in another country's operator if it is the same company?

Tags: cellphones

I'm not sure that this is the correct site for my question, but didn't find a better one.

My situation: I have a phone that is locked to a mobile phone operator (e.g. Vodafone) in Hungary. Can I use this phone in the UK with a SIM card from a UK phone operator (e.g. Vodafone UK)?

Comment: Depends on how they've locked it, but as Vodafone UK and Vodafone HU have different network IDs, the answer is probably "No"

Comment: Vodafone will unlock your phone for 10 000 Ft, or in some cases, free.

Answer (score 2):

The safest answer is "quite possibly not".
It certainly does not work with Vodafone in some cross border situations.

Michael suggested that Vodafone will unlock it for money or free, but unless his answer is based on specific Hungarian and UK examples it's not a safe one.

A year or so ago Vodafone Australia refused to unlock a phone owned by my wife and locked to the Vodafone NZ network, even though it was many years old and obviously out of any contractual requirement for locking.

So, safest idea would seem to be to contact Vodafone UK and ask.

Comment: I am not surprised that Vodafone AU would not touch your phone. New Zealand is another country, not East Australia! I _would_ be surprised if Vodafone NZ refused to unlock it.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Aye. Tis so. But Hungary & UK are also different countries. Hungary is not East UK. Which was the point of his question. My example exactly matches his question wrt 2 countries, but you said they would unlock his phone, but are "not surprised" that they would not unlock ours. What am I (or you) missing ?  || Hmm: Depends where he is and where you thought he was. If he is in Hungary then all SHOULD be well. If he is in UK (or anywhere but Hungary) then he may well be out of luck.

Comment: I proposed that he unlock his phone via Vodafone HU, and even quoted the price that they give.